# Button in Bootstrap HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted a button where you hover it and it displays a text. 
Here is my code so far.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."> 
    Popover on bottom 
</button>`
```

I visited many websites and they have a similar code for the button. I am using bootstrap. I just cannot figure out why that code isn't working.

Here is the code for how I imported my .js file of bootstrap

```
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Am I doing something terribly wrong? All websites say the same thing but I just get a pretty button which doesn't display any text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tout activate it and add Jquery. Also you don't need .min.is and .js :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." id="example"> Popover on bottom </button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$('#example').popover()</script>
```

Comment: I tried a lot of times. Even made a new page with just that code it just doesn't work.

Comment: I got it. I put the script ABOVE the button and it came. I usually place it below but whatever! THANKS :D

Comment: What do I do if the content display is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include both of these js files.

min.js is for the live website.
.js is for the development site.

Remove one of the js files and see if it works.

Also make sure you have the js files in the right directory